# Can I make a hardened ISO image for use

Tags: operating-systems, architecture, images

I am needing to spin up a VM and harden it to some standards. I realize that I might have to do this multiple times and I am not really up for a parallel ssh session on several boxes.

Is there a way that I can spin up one VM, harden it, and save it as an ISO or something that can be used as a standard in our environment?

Comment: Generally, you can take a snapshot of a VM so you are able to restart it from that exact point at any time. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No. Snapshot.is a snapshot and has memory and a lot of things to bloat the machine;essentially , a copy of the machine having mac addr info and other things . This would make it more difficult in the long run.

Comment: Does it need to be an ISO, specifically? In order to harden an ISO, you would either need to have a system that naturally supports persistence (such as Alpine Linux, where the ISO is _overlayed_ with custom configuration changes), or you would need to unpack, modify, and repack the ISO, for example to introduce sysctl changes in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or whatever.

Comment: This is not a security question. The only bit about security is that you will have configured the VM to be considered "hardened", which is only a minor detail.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to do anything. The initial VM is your standard template. You can shutdown the VM and copy it in as many copies as you need. You will only need to change the MAC and IP on the new copies.